# Expires Headers not recognized

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I test my webpage statistics on www.gtmetrix.com. Although, I have added expiration dates in my  .htaccess file both manually and through W3 Total Cache plugin, on the Yslow results tab, it gives the following warning

```
Add Expires headers 
There are 51 static components without a far-future expiration date.

    https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-129793039-1
    https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7COpen+Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%7CSource+Sans+Pro%3A200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext%2Cdevanagari%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Cvietnamese%2Ccyrillic%2Cgreek-ext%2Cgreek&ver=5.2.1
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logomydomain_text.png
    https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2
    https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600%2C700
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/images/dummy.png
    https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-5RJHR3Q
    https://example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.2.1
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/IMG_8094_3-2-e1562279039927-600x387.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/cagdas-yazicioglu-600x387.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DSC_0035-2-600x387.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/82_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/65_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/100_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/41_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/08_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/36_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/79_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/71_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/01-kopya.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/04.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Ekran-Resmi-2018-10-19-03.02.39-706x1024-e1540483971798-150x150.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Ekran-Resmi-2018-10-19-01.02.56-683x1024-e1540387642379-150x150.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DSC_0035-2-150x150.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DSC_0128-150x150.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logomydomain_text-300x221.png
    https://example.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js
    https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZ5DZBiwD_UgATR2xb-PzlnVsKbf7Kbd4&libraries=geometry%2Cplaces%2Cweather%2Cpanoramio%2Cdrawing&language=tr&ver=5.2.1
    https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
    https://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js
    https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/css/translateelement.css
    https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/js/element/main.js
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mydomainl.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Layer-0.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/contact-bg.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js?version=5.4.8
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js?version=5.4.8
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?version=5.4.8
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js?version=5.4.8
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js?version=5.4.8
    https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Ana-Slider.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/04_b.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/89_b.png
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=google-maps-embed&paint_origin=&libraries=geometry,search&v=3.exp&language=en&region=tr&callback=onApiLoad
    https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0k2vxpozp
    https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0k2vxpp00
    https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/l?client=te&alpha=true&hl=en&cb=_callbacks____0k2vxpp0d
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/logomydomain.png
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/sliderfoto1-22.jpg
    https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/sliderfoto2-.jpg
```

You can see my current .htaccess file with ExpiresByType

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType application/javascript .js2
    AddType text/javascript .js3
    AddType text/x-js .js4
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xsd .xsd
    AddType text/xsl .xsl
    AddType text/xml .xml
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType application/json .json
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
         Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
         Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.xml%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have reviewed many similar questions on StackOverflow and tried the given solutions. However, they couldn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *example.com* is your domain name you, it seems that the .htaccess rules you provide are overwritten thus they are not validated. Check for another .htaccess the directory before your website root folder.

In my experience so far I have witness this only on a cPanel server after enabling the "Optimize Website" feature which is build in cPanel. If this is the case you should have .htaccess file in your homedeir:

```
/home/cp-user/.htaccess
```

Where *cp-user* is your actual cPanel username. The file content looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/pw4793). If this is the case you can navigate to cPanel Software -> Software Optimization and select the "**Disabled**" option, which will remove all of the code in the .htaccess file in your account homedir. The other option is to manually remove the content of the .htaccess file by FTP, SSH or cPanel's File Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your assumption is correct I have changed my domain with example.com. Unfortunately, I am hosting my site on a VPS and no cPanel installed in the system. I have searched for other .htaccess files but couldn't find any